# need help to filter data for a specific year in a table however date defined as varchar. how to write my join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, date-conversion

Please find below my code. I am joining 3 table using join and filtering data for year 2012 to see total sale for in this year. Please not sales_date column in sales table defined as varchar (format = mm/dd/yyyy)

```
SELECT country.name, parts.name,
SUM(parts.price * sales.quantity) AS total_sales
FROM sales JOIN country ON country.id=sales.country_id
JOIN parts ON parts.id=sales.model_id
WHERE sales.sales_date between '1/1/2012' and '12/31/2012'
GROUP BY country.name,parts.name
ORDER BY total_sales asc;
```

Above query giving me result for all and not filtering for particular year. Please let me know if you have any question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to fix the data!  Dates should be stored using native date/time formats.  And broken data can (often) be fixed.

If that is not possible, then you can use string operations to get the year.  In this case, `like` does what you want:

```
where sales.sales_date like '%2012'
```

**Do not use `LIKE` on `date`/`datetime` data!**. It is designed for strings and here you are using it on a string.

To fix your data, you can do the following.

First, put the dates into a proper YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
update sales
    set sales_date = str_to_date(sales.date, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Then modify the column:

```
alter table sales modify column sales_date date;
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried as suggested but it was showing error. now its giving me expected result. Please note, i cant chng data format. though suggested already to change